# Does virtual `operator <=>` with default implementation make one more virtual method in C++20?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, comparison-operators

If one makes `virtual` C++20 three-way comparison operator `<=>` with the default implementation, then the compiler silently makes one more virtual `operator==`, as can be shown by overriding it in a child class:

```
struct A { 
    virtual std::strong_ordering operator <=>(const A &) const = default; 
};
struct B : A {
    virtual bool operator==(const A&) const noexcept override;
};
```

All three major compilers behaves that way, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nvaf94M51

Is it mandated by the standard or just a common implementation practice?

As a side observation, in C++20 we also have an ability to make `consteval` immediate virtual functions, and if the example is extended:

```
#include <compare>

struct A { 
    virtual consteval std::strong_ordering operator <=>(const A &) const = default; 
};

struct B : A {
    virtual consteval bool operator==(const A&) const noexcept override { return false; }
};

int main() {
    static constexpr B b;
    static constexpr const A & a = b;
    static_assert( (a <=> a) == 0 );
    static_assert( a != a );
    return (a <=> a) == 0; 
}
```

then it introduces certain difficulties to the modern compilers: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Gsz39Kr5b

Clang crashes, and GCC produces a program, which fails during execution. Are these just some compiler bugs, or the program is not well formed?

Comment: From design point of view, `virtual operator ==` has several issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it mandated by the standard or just a common implementation practice?

It is mandated. [[class.compare.default]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.compare.default#5):

> If the *member-specification* does not explicitly declare any member or friend named `operator==`, an `==` operator function is declared implicitly for each three-way comparison operator function defined as defaulted in the *member-specification*, with the same access and *function-definition* and in the same class scope as the respective three-way comparison operator function, except that the return type is replaced with `bool` and the *declarator-id* is replaced with `operator==`.
>
> [Note [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.compare.default#note-2): Such an implicitly-declared `==` operator for a class `X` is defined as defaulted in the definition of `X` and has the same *parameter-declaration-clause* and trailing *requires-clause* as the respective three-way comparison operator.
> It is declared with `friend`, `virtual`, `constexpr`, or `consteval` if the three-way comparison operator function is so declared. ... — end note]
>
> [Example [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.compare.default#example-1):
>
> ```cpp
> template<typename T> struct X {
>  friend constexpr std::partial_ordering operator<=>(X, X) requires (sizeof(T) != 1) = default;
>  // implicitly declares: friend constexpr bool operator==(X, X) requires (sizeof(T) != 1) = default;
>
>  [[nodiscard]] virtual std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const X&) const = default;
>  // implicitly declares: [[nodiscard]] virtual bool operator==(const X&) const = default;
> };
> ```
>
> — end example]